# How to loop through all files in Jekyll's _data folder?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How can I loop through every file in my _data folder in Jekyll?

Currently I have a list of files in a file called sidebarlist.yml like this:

```
- file1
- file2
- file3
```

In order to loop through all of these files, I use this code:

```
{% for sidebar in site.data.sidebarlist %}
{% for entry in site.data.sidebars[sidebar].entries %}
...
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to avoid using sidebarlist.yml and just iterate through all files within _data automatically. Can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Nesting loops allows you to loop through the contents of _data files.

When I did this I used a [subdirectory](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/#subfolders), since I didn't want to loop through every data file, and I think that applies to many use cases. It also keeps my _data directory a little tidier.

My _data directory looks like this:

```
_data/
  navigation.yml
  news.yml
  people/
    advisors.yml
    board.yml
    staff.yml
```

Each of the files within people/ uses a structure like this:

```
- name: Anne Smith
  role: Role A
  url: mysite.com
- name: Joe Shmoe
  role: Role B
  url: mysite.org
```

And on the page where I'm looping through each of these data files:

```
{% for people_hash in site.data.people %}
{% assign people = people_hash[1] %}

  {% for person in people %}

    <li>{{ person.name }}, {{ person.role }}</li>

  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

This results in:

```
<li>Anne Smith, Role A</li>
<li>Joe Shmoe, Role B</li>
```

It's very similar to what you've already done, but eliminates the need for that extra yaml file.

---

Note the use of `people_hash[1]` - this is what is targeting the appropriate values within the array.

If instead you do:

```
{% for people_hash in site.data.people %}
{% assign people = people_hash[1] %}

    <pre>{{ people }}</pre>

{% endfor %}
```

You'll get the array of values that is returned, which should help you debug your template.

Comment: Great answer; assuming OP wants to iterate through a flat list of yaml files, this solution works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question title, and I will answer your last question:

You can't loop through files you keep in _data folder. According to [Jekyll Variable doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) and  Jekyll Directory structure all the file in `_data` with supported extension `.yml .yaml .csv .json`by default will be loaded in site.data like @wasthishelpfull's answered and you access it via `{{site.data.*filename.data*}}` and loop though like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453960/accessing-data-in-jekyll-loop-in-loop)

If you wanna loop through files, create a folder `(no underscore)` serve it as static files, and use jquery.get() for the data in the file.

Or change `_data` to `data` in `_config.yml` by adding `data_source: data` and access at a url endpoint `/data` [see this post for more](https://esq.io/blog/posts/dogfooding-with-jekyll/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/), jekyll will load YAML resources (.yml, .yaml, .json, and .csv files) directly into `site.data`. If your files use one of these formats, you can do:

```
{% for data in site.data %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, while this does load the data files, it doesn't quite work for what I'm trying to accomplish. Maybe my use case is more complicated, since I'm trying to go into a specific yaml level within each of the files.

Comment: I wasn't sure to understand what you're trying to accomplish, so I didn't elaborate my answer. Feel free to precise your use case :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to [access](https://raisedbyturtles.org/shopify-associative-arrays) jekyll `site.data` in a way of [looping multi levels object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48440589/4058484):

```
{% assign my_data = site.data %}
{% assign my_level = "sidebarlist.sidebars.sidebar" | split: "." %}

{% for level in my_level %}
    {% assign my_data = my_data[level[i]] %}
    {% for data in my_data %}
        {{ data }} : {{ my_data[data] }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```