# How to loop through all files in Jekyll's _data folder, and pull their filenames?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Similar to the question at [How to loop through all files in Jekyll's _data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579632/how-to-loop-through-all-files-in-jekylls-data-folder), how would one loop through the files in their /_data directory (or a subdirectory) and pull the filenames of each file?

for example, if you had:

```
_data/
  navigation.yml
  news.yml
  people/
    advisors.yml
    board.yml
    staff.yml
```

... and you wanted to get the list of files inside /_data/people/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loop through the subdirectory, each for item (in this case "file") will have file[0] as the filename (without the extension) and file[1] as the content of the file.

Thus, your code can look like:

```
{% for file in site.data.people %}
  {{ file[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

would result in:

```
advisors
board
staff
```